# Is it possible to turn data from a server into native layout in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, user-interface

We are looking at options for loading dynamic content and layout for an iOS app. We are trying to stay away from loading html in webviews (ie, PhoneGap).

Something like:
1. App requests a view from the server.
2. Server sends back some textual data describing the view.
3. App turns the text into UIButtons, UIViews, UITableViews, etc and puts them into their respective places as described in the view.

Does anyone know of a tool or framework that can take some information (JSON, XML, whatever) and turn it into a layout with native objects?

Comment: You could probably send a compiled XIB file and unarchive that in your app.

Comment: You can certainly construct a UI view on the fly, based on some description.  Finding code already written to do this is another matter.  (And I'd be a little concerned about sending an XIB, from a security standpoint.)